# 'Test' section is not displayed while browsing TFS for executing test cases on browser

Tags: tfs

I am not able to see **Test** section when I browse to the TFS.
I have tried this with all the **Team Project Templates** I am not able to view for any.
Is there something I have missed while configuring/setting the TFS or the Team Project?
These projects have test case as work items. Yet options to execute test on browser is not displayed whereas I can see test cases in **Work Items** and I can update also them.

[image: Test Section]

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/10/08/enabling-test-case-management-features-in-team-foundation-server-web-access.aspx

Comment: @Oswald: I am using VS Professional 2012 Update 4 still i am not able to see the same. Plus appending _/_Testmanagement_ to team project URL is also not working

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/02/12/light-weight-browser-based-test-management-and-execution.aspx

Comment: @Oswald: This link is also mentioning the same, i don't think there is any such problem with latest CTP the problem was occurring with the first update only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the account you are using is setup as a Full Access account in the TFS Control Panel.

[image]

Comment: TFS is installed on my local machine and my account is the admin of the same.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you're TFS Admin or not, you need to go into the TFS Control Panel (by clicking on the gears in the top-right in web access) and mark your account as Full (it is not the default).